# SAP NetWeaver & R

Tags: r, sap-gui

I found that the issue on how to connect R to SAP is as old as year 2012
For example link below, there's a tutorial on how to link R and SAP

https://blogs.sap.com/2012/06/21/analytics-with-sap-and-r-windows-version/

The R package to link R and SAP is

https://github.com/piersharding/RSAP

I have the SAP GUI for Windows installed on my machine as below:

[image]

Based on the install script here, I need to specify the path to `nwrfcsdk` folder:

https://github.com/piersharding/RSAP/blob/master/INSTALL

```
library(devtools)
install_github('RSAP', username='piersharding', args=c("--configure-args=--with-nwrfcsdk-include=C:/nwrfcsdk/include --with-nwrfcsdk-lib=C:/nwrfcsdk/lib' --no-clean-on-error"))
```

When I look at my current SAP GUI for Windows installation path, there's no `lib` folder.

So I'm not sure how can I make the installation.

[image]

UPDATE
I've asked my IT team to get me the nwrfcsdk, which I then parked at C:\

[image]

However I still face installation issue

```
> remotes::install_github('piersharding/RSAP', args=c("--configure-args='--with-nwrfcsdk-include=C:/nwrfcsdk/include --with-nwrfcsdk-lib=C:/nwrfcsdk/lib' --no-clean-on-error"))
Downloading GitHub repo piersharding/RSAP@master
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6Fl8b5\remotes247857351b30\piersharding-RSAP-94103bc/DESCRIPTION' (555ms)
-  preparing 'RSAP':
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  cleaning src
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (1.5s)
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'RSAP_0.13.tar.gz'
   Warning: file 'RSAP/cleanup' did not have execute permissions: corrected
   Warning: file 'RSAP/configure' did not have execute permissions: corrected

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'RSAP' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
Error: (converted from warning) this package has a non-empty 'configure.win' file,
so building only the main architecture
* removing 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/RSAP'
Error: Failed to install 'RSAP' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp6Fl8b5/file2478391ea47/RSAP_0.13.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: You are confusing the two software SAP GUI for Windows (used for the presentation of ABAP screens) and SAP Netweaver... I guess it should work with an ABAP application server, see there: [AS ABAP 7.52 SP04, developer edition: Concise installation guide](http://blogs.sap.com/2019/10/01/as-abap-7.52-sp04-developer-edition-concise-installation-guide)

Comment: @SandraRossi I don't quite understand how does the ABAP SP04 will solve the issue of connecting R and SAP though. Could you please explain further? Thank you

Comment: Hi @SandraRossi, noted, I'm checking with my IT team on SAP NetWeaver installation. But I'm quite confused if I don't have SAP NetWeaver, then how is it possible that all this while I'm able to extract data using the SAP GUI? How can I check for SAP NetWeaver installation path?

Comment: Sorry. I understand now that you have said "SAP NetWeaver" when it was "SAP GUI for Windows". Let me edit your question.

Comment: For clarification, why is it SAP NetWeaver is shown when I open SAP GUI? Does it not mean I already have SAP NetWeaver? if yes, where's the path??

Comment: [SAP NetWeaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_NetWeaver) is not software, it's kind of marketing, a brand or suite of miscellaneous software. SAP GUI for Windows is part of SAP NetWeaver (that doesn't mean anything except marketing stuff).

Comment: @SandraRossi From here https://github.com/piersharding/RSAP/blob/master/INSTALL, the author says 'install the SAP NW RFC SDK'. So what is this SAP NW RFC SDK? Is it a SAP NetWeaver or not? Or is it ABAP SP04 that you mentioned?

Comment: The RFC SDK is a separate "software" (a SDK), neither SAP GUI nor ABAP server.